# How to preserve datatype of column while using to_csv()

Tags: python, pandas, export-to-csv, data-analysis

I'm changing `int` datatype to `str` datatype of a column using `astype()` and  saving it to [csv](/questions/tagged/csv) file using `to_csv()`. But reading the same [csv](/questions/tagged/csv) file by `read_csv()` says the datatype is int only. I don't want to use `dtype=str` while reading the file.
Below is the following information:

```py
df.info()
#dtypes: int64(1), object(1)
    
df = df.astype(str)

df.info()
#dtypes: object(2)

df.to_csv('answer.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8')
df = pd.read_csv('answer.csv')

df.info()
#dtypes: int64(1), object(1)
```

Is there any way by which, while saving [csv](/questions/tagged/csv) file, only datatype of the column also gets saved with the changed datatype and not with the original datatype?

Comment: CSVs don’t have types, that information is never preserved. CSVs only have strings. Any type is being interpreted by the reading library.

Comment: If you want to preserve type information you might want to try [to_parquet](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#io-parquet) instead of csv.

Comment: But I want to save file in csv format only.

Comment: @deceze ?? you don't understand the problem here.

Answer (score 4):

you can meet the requirement by create a data_map csv file if csv is the only option.

When export dataframe to csv, you can create another csv, which store the column type info.

when import csv to dataframe, you can read the data_map csv and convert to a dictionary in advance. use it to explicitly load csv data in specific data type. 
dtype params can offer such a function.

dtype : Type name or dict of column -> type, default None
Data type for data or columns. E.g. {'a': np.float64, 'b': np.int32} (unsupported with engine='python'). Use str or object together with suitable na_values settings to preserve and not interpret dtype.

New in version 0.20.0: support for the Python parser.
[enter link description here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#io-read-csv-table)

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

# Create a sample DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'column1': [1, 2, 3], 'column2': ['A', 'B', 'C']})

# Set the data type of column1 to int32
df['column1'] = df['column1'].astype('int32')

# Write the DataFrame to a CSV file, preserving the data type of column1
df.to_csv('output.csv', index=False, dtype={'column1': 'int32'})
```

Comment: DataFrame.to_csv has no argument "dtype".
`TypeError: to_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dtype'`

Answer (score -2):

First import the module

```
import pandas as pd
```

Create a sample DataFrame with a column of datetime objects

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'dates': [pd.Timestamp('2022-01-01'), pd.Timestamp('2022-01-02')]})
```

Specify the data types of the columns using the dtype parameter

```
dtypes = {'dates': 'datetime64'}
```

Write the DataFrame to a CSV file while preserving the datatypes

```
df.to_csv('my_file.csv', index=False, dtype=dtypes)
```

Answer (score -5):

```
df.to_csv('answer.csv', index=False, index_label = True, encoding='utf-8')
```

you can use `index_label = True`

Comment: This is just completely wrong: index_label stores only the header of the dataframe, and save it as first row in the outputted csv. There is no information stored about the column format info (integer,string,datetime, etc.)

Comment: This doesn't preserve strings as mentioned in @bot's example.